# Merging vector + map Versions of a Function to a Single Compatible Version

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, template-function

Those are my two overloaded function for `std::map` container and for `std::vector` container with Lambda expression.

Does anybody see a way to make it template-function which can check for the Lambda expression for `pair` type (in my case the second of pair) and regular range type (like `vector`, `deque`, etc).

```
bool isPlayerIn(vector<Player*> players, int id) {
    vector<Player*>::iterator found = find_if(begin(players), end(players),
                                              [id] (Player* player) {
        return player->getId() == id;
        });
     return found != end(players);
}

bool isPlayerIn(map<int, Player*> players, int id) {
     map<int, Player*>::iterator found = find_if(begin(players), end(players),
                                                 [id] (pair<int, Player*> found) {
        return found.second->getId() == id;
        });
     return found != end(players);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with some [*template metaprogramming*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3743/A-gentle-introduction-to-Template-Metaprogramming), specifically something like [Boost's `is_pair`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/numeric/odeint/util/is_pair.hpp). The idea is to "push down" the differentiation from the algorithm to the functor.

Note that for a very short function of the type you wrote, you might not find this an improvement; for longer functions, involving more complex algorithms, this would remove a lot of the duplication.

so, you'd have two classes like so:

```
template<typename T, bool Pair> 
matches_id : 
    std::unary_function<T, bool>
{
    // Ctor taking id
    // operator() deciding if t.second matches id
};

template<typename T>
matches_id<T, false> : 
    std::unary_function<T, bool>
{
    // Ctor taking id
    // operator() deciding if t itself matches id
};
```

In your code, you'd use `find_if` with an object of type

```
matches_id<T, is_pair<T>::value>
```

Comment: Ok, yes, I see. But if, for example, I work just with two containers, vector and map, two functions with overloading will do the job. And if I want to work with all range iterator and pair, this is the generic solution. Actually, this does work by the same principle of overloading, but with additional component of is_pair, which checks in the compile process and make the decision which matches will run. Right ?
But there isn't solution, which prevent double code for the template-function matches_id.

Comment: Even if you know in advance that you will work with just vector and map - if the algorithm is complex/long enough, this type of stuff can remove most of the duplication.